# Alarm is setting for UTC timestamp.. Not for my current system time

Tags: android, date, calendar, broadcastreceiver, android-alarms

I am making an Alarm time application.. Alarm is working right... but it is working on based on UTC time. I want to run alarm at my time local time..

I have following code in my startAlarm method of broadcast receiver:

```
Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, SilentModeOnBroadCastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, j, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date1.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Please help me in this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass your Local TimeZone to `Calender.getInstance()` Method

```
  TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("LocalTimeZone");//Your Own Local TimeZone
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
```